# Работа компонента SHFILEOPSTRUCT с русским текстом

Tags: c++builder, c++

Вопрос по компоненту SHFILEOPSTRUCT. Точнее о его работе с русским текстом.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы копировать файлы из одной папки в другую. Спасибо за помощь!

```
 String slSourceDir1= "C:\\ПапкаИзКоторйБудутКопироватьсяФайлы\\*.*";
 String slTargetDir1 = "C:\\ПапкаВКоторуюБудутКопироватьсяФайлы";

  SHFILEOPSTRUCT   SHF ;

  SHF.hwnd = 0;
  SHF.pFrom = slSourceDir1.c_str();
  SHF.pTo = slTargetDir1.c_str();
  SHF.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
  SHF.wFunc = FO_COPY;

  String Text = "Резервное копирование файлов 1С.";
  SHF.fFlags = SHF.fFlags | FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS;
  SHF.lpszProgressTitle = Text.c_str();

  if( SHFileOperation(&SHF) != 0)
    if (SHF.fAnyOperationsAborted)
      ShowMessage(
           "Выполнение операции прервано пользователем");
    else ShowMessage("Ошибка выполнения операции");
  else ShowMessage("Операция успешно завершена");
```

Получается вот что. Папка-приемник может быть и с русским текстом, а вот папка, из которой берутся файлы, категорически ругается. Если же название сделать английским, то все проходит ровно. Такая вот проблема.

Answer (score 1):

[Согласно MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795(v=VS.85).aspx) структура SHFILEOPSTRUCT объявляет поля

```
LPCTSTR      pFrom;
LPCTSTR      pTo;
```

как строки типа LPCTSTR, а не LPCSTR. Поэтому конвертация строк должна быть другой

```
SHF.pFrom = slSourceDir1.t_str();
SHF.pTo = slTargetDir1.t_str();
```

И проект должен быть Unicode. Еще где-то в настройка C++Builder есть опция "TCHAR maps to", которая может влиять на преобразования строк.